# Setting font size in CSS distorting input boxes spaces

Tags: html, css

i am making a crosswords page, i create text inputs and append them to a div and this is the css class

```
.whiteCell {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
color: black;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
cursor: context-menu;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 5px;}
```

when removing the font size everything looks ok but when adding it looks distorted as you can see in these 2 images

[here it looks ok without font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaRPO.png)

[here is the distorted version after adding font size to css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZho8.png)

is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: vertical-algin:top

Comment: Can you share the html code?

Comment: thanks alot @TemaniAfif this helped alot on desktop, but still distorted on mobile like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG876.jpg

Comment: try adding `-moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif searched on the internet and found this and did it already but still no effect